# The use of adverbs "most" and "best" in context

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Tell me please if there is any difference between the following sentences.

> I like fried fish the **best**.
>
> I like fried fish the **most**.

By the way, what if I omit the definite article, will the meaning change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> - I like fried fish the best.
> - I like fried fish the most.
> - I like fried fish best.
> - I like fried fish most.

All of these are acceptable and natural, although the last would be in informal speech, or with previous clarifying context.

> I like fish, meatloaf, and pasta, but I like fried fish most.

All carry much the same meaning. All imply a comparison with some unstated list of alternative choices, possibly all imaginable foods. Context may suggest a more limited list.

The forms without the article are more clearly comparisons to an elided or previously stated set of alternatives.